# How can I select random N number of questions from array containing many questions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, random

I am trying to make a quiz with React that displays **random 100 questions** from a javascript file.

Here are the questions inside javascript file.

```js
const quizQuestions = [
 
 {
  question: "Grand Central Terminal, Park Avenue, New York is the world's",
  options: ["largest railway station", "highest railway station", "longest railway station", "None of the above"],
  answer: "largest railway station"
 },
 {
  question: "Entomology is the science that studies",
  options: ["Behavior of human beings", "Insects", "The origin and history of technical and scientific terms", "The formation of rocks"],
  answer: "The origin and history of technical and scientific terms"
 },
 {
  question: "Eritrea, which became the 182nd member of the UN in 1993, is in the continent of",
  options: ["Asia", "Africa", "Europe", "Australia"],
  answer: "Africa"
 },
 {
  question: "Garampani sanctuary is located at",
  options: ["Junagarh, Gujarat", "Diphu, Assam", "Kohima, Nagaland", "Gangtok, Sikkim"],
  answer: "Diphu, Assam"
 },
 {
  question: "Hitler party which came into power in 1933 is known as",
  options: ["Labour Party", "Nazi Party", "Ku-Klux-Klan","Democratic Party"],
  answer: "Nazi Party"
 }
 
]

export default quizQuestions;
```

**1. I need javascript code to select for example 3 random questions in random order from above file. Similarly randomize options** without repetition of question

**2. And I want to execute the following function as many times as the no of questions by calling the component `MCQ` and passing the question and option as props**

```js
function MCQ(props) {

 return(
  <div>
   <div>{props.question}</div>
   <div> 
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id=??? /><label for="???"> {props.options[0]}</label>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id=??? /><label for="???"> {props.options[1]}</label>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id=??? /><label for="???"> {props.options[2]}</label>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id=??? /><label for="???"> {props.options[3]}</label>
   </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

What **id** and **name** should i give?

THANK YOU

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site. SO is not a free code writing service - it is for where you have attempted to solve your problem and got stuck with a particular bit of it

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you can use random function . Just add following line of code in your function:

```
let ind= Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(quiz.length));
console.log(ind);
```

console.log(quiz[ind].question)

Then you can export two variable index and quizQuestion . Then use just as you ha e used in your MCQ function

```
Quiz[index].options [0]
```

I hope you get the answer. Hope you get the answer.